# Strange error with NSSecureTextField in NSOpenPanel's accessory view

Tags: macos, cocoa, sdk, nsopenpanel

in my app I use an NSOpenPanel with an accessory view. This view has, among other things, a NSSecureTextField. Every time I open the panel this notice shows up in the log:

```
NSSecureTextFieldCell detected a field editor ((null)) that is 
not a NSTextView subclass designed to work with the cell. Ignoring...
```

Does anybody know what exactly this means and how to get rid of it?
For now it isn't causing any problems but I would like to remove this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you created subclass of NSSecureTextfield??

Comment: No. I simply used IB to paste it into the view and linked it to the controller.

Comment: Can you paste your code here??

Comment: The only code I basically use is in the *.h file:
`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSSecureTextField *passwordField;`
and in the initialization method:
`[self.passwordField.cell setPlaceholderString:NSLocalizedString(@"Enter Password", @"")];` 

Later on I sometimes check the string value of the field.

Comment: Can you try like this [self.passwordField.cell setPlaceholderString:NSLocalizedString(@"Enter Password")];

Comment: This will cause an error.

Comment: Is this for an app that you hope to eventually have on the App Store?  If not, turn off sandboxing and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Yes, it's for the AppStore so unfortunately I can't turn it off.